# Postgresql-hll (or another Hyperloglog data type/structure) for Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, hyperloglog

Need to be able to report on Unique Visitors, but would like to avoid pre-computing every possible permutation of keys and creating multiple tables.

As a simplistic example, let's say I need to report Monthly Uniques in a table that has the following columns

- date (Month/Year)
- page_id
- country_id
- device_type_id
- monthly_uniques

In Druid and Redis, Hyperloglog data type will take care of this (assuming a small margin of error is acceptable), where I would be able to run a query by any combination of the dimensions and receive a viable estimate of the uniques.

Closest I was able to find in PostgreSQL world is postgresql-hll plugin, but it seems to be for PostgreSQL 9.0+.

Is there a way to represent this in Redshift without either having to pre-compute or store visitor IDs (greatly inflating the table size, but allowing to use RedShift's "approximate count" hll implementation)?

Note: RedShift is the preferred platform, but I already know that other self-hosted PostgreSQL forks can support this, such as CitusDB. Looking for ways to do this with RedShift.

Comment: Unless something has changed since last I looked, redshift does not allow custom types or plugins. I know they added custom function support for python functions, so you should be able to implement the hll algorithm as a function, but that's likely work you'll have to do on your own.

Comment: At query level, hll is implemented using "approximate" keyword before the count in select statement. Unfortunately, this only works if you have raw or close to raw data. I'm trying to avoid having to store all of this. Docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COUNT.html

Comment: Redshift speaks the postgres line protocol, but it was forked a very long time ago, and has changed functionality significantly. Since there is no ability to do custom types, then I don't think what you're asking for is possible.

Comment: @jmelesky Could you please post this as an answer? Confirmed that you are 100% correct and there isn't a way to do this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Redshift, while technically postgresql-derived, was forked over ten years ago. It still speaks the same line protocol as postgres, but its code has diverged a great deal. Among other incompatibilities, it no longer allows for custom datatypes. That means that the type of plugin you're looking to use is not going to be feasible.

However, as you pointed out, if you're able to get all the raw data in, you can use the built-in approximation capability.

Answer (score 1):

Redshift recently announced support for HyperLogLog Sketches:

- https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/amazon-redshift-announces-support-hyperloglog-sketches/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/hyperloglog-overview.html
- UPDATE: blog post on HLL usage https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/use-hyperloglog-for-trend-analysis-with-amazon-redshift/

Answer (score 1):

Redshift announced new HLL capabilities in October 2020. If your Redshift release version is 1.0.19097 or later, you can use all HLL functions available. See more at [AWS Redshift documentation here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/amazon-redshift-announces-support-hyperloglog-sketches/)

You can do something like

```
SELECT hll(column_name) AS unique_count FROM YOURTABLE;
```

or create [HLL sketches directly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_HLL_CREATE_SKETCH.html)